# Dapper default behaviour when requesting an int from a complex object

Tags: c#, dapper

Recently we came across a scenario within our code base where we were using dapper to map a complex object too an int. This code seems to work and returns the Id. How does dapper resolve from a complex object to a simple base object i.e. will it be using the first value returned in the query or the key field?

```
public int GetId(int fkId)
{           
    const string sql = @"SELECT * 
                    FROM myTable 
                    WHERE myForeignKey = @fkId";

    using (var conn = _connectionHelper.GetConnection())
    {
        return conn.Query<int>(sql, new
        {
            fkId
        }).First();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed as soon as it was spotted. Was more interested in why it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/fe5c270aceab362c936456087a830e6fe1603cac/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L672):

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a query, returning the data typed as per T
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A sequence of data of the supplied type;
/// if a basic type (int, string, etc) is queried then the data
/// from the first column in assumed, otherwise an instance is
/// created per row, and a direct column-name===member-name mapping
/// is assumed (case insensitive).
/// </returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>
```

So it just grabs the first column. Which is why using `select *` is risky.

Regardless of how it works, you should change it. You should be explicit in declaring which fields you want to select, and you shouldn't select fields that aren't needed. If you just need to get a single value back from a query, you can use `QuerySingle` or `ExecuteScalar`.

With open source projects, don't be afraid to actually go look at the source code when you have a question about how they work.